# React Router <Link> to dynamic page and go back to previous state in useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to make a React app with dynamic pages and navigational fetch with next and previous buttons, when click on the Item  it shows the page dynamic page but when I press the back button on the browser it forgets the state where count and input value and shows the initial state. What should I write to save the state so that when I go back it stays on the same count and value and not start from initial state?

```
const App = () => {
    return (
        <Router>
            Route path='/item/:id' component={Item} />
            Route path='/' exact component={Search} />
        </Router>
    )
}

const Items = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            {props.data.map(image => (
                /* Link to component Item */ 
                <Link to={`/item/${image.id}`} key={image.id}>
                <img src={image.urls.small} alt={image.description} />
                </Link>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}

const Search = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        getData();
    },[count]);

    const nextPage = (event) => {
        setCount(count + 1);
        getData();
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    const prevPage = event => {
        if (count > 1) {
            setCount(count - 1);
            getData();
        }
    event.preventDefault();
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Items data={images} />
            <button onClick={prevPage}>PREV</button>
            <button onClick={nextPage}>NEXT</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you may need to look into state management systems/patterns. What you are looking for is called persistence, where you can revisit a page and maintain the same values in the same session.

Your form state is being cleared because you're holding it in a "local" component state - a component that is being re-rendered every time you switch pages. The "easy" way to solve this is to manage the `Search` component's state inside of `App` and add all the handlers to `App` as well, this is also called "raising" the state. While this is the "easy" way to do things, it is also quick and dirty (you will probably need to refactor in the future) because it will eventually overcomplicate your `App` component if you add other page/form states, etc.

The other way (also quick and easy and what I would recommend) is to store your search values in `localStorage`. You can save them in a JSON format to be read and used to update the form as soon as the component mounts. I think if this is a small app, this is probably the best way.

The approach for larger applications (3+ pages) is to use a global state management system, Flux, Redux, Mobx etc. These systems make it much easier to maintain a global app state and persist information even if you navigate through different pages in the app (as long as you maintain the session). This approach, while I recommend you look into for practice is usually left fort larger applications and can add too much overhead for what its worth on smaller apps.

Answer (score 0):

Another 'quick win' approach is to utilize ReactRouter's `state`. Basically you can set state properties to a particular point in the router's history. I've used this before to remember scroll position of a lazy-loading grid.

What this does is applies your state to the current browser history position, so when you navigate elsewhere and then hit back on your browser navigation bar, the previous state is also restored (not just the URL).

In essence, create your own `Link` component wrapper:

```
import React from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class CustomLink extends React.Component {
  handleClick(e) {
    const { count, input, history } = this.props;
    state = { count, input }

    history.replace({ state });
  }

  render() {
    const { to, children } = this.props;
    return (
      <Link
        onClick={this.handleClick}
        to={to}
      >
        {children}
      </Link>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(CustomLink);
```